# How to solve the recurrence relation T(n) = 8T(n/2) + 1000 n2 by Master's Theorem

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

How to solve the recurrence relation T(N) = 8T(N/2) + 100 N^2 by the Master's Theorem.

Comment: This sounds like a math question more than a programming question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have used `100` and `1000` in your description and question respectively.

The solution of this
**Note: Considering 100**

```
 T(n) = 100 (nlog(2)(8))
```

As, you should know that if
**If a > b^k, then T(n) = θ (nlogba)**

```
In you case a = 8, b = 2 and k=2
hence a>b^k
```